# How create case-independent intentfilter?

Tags: android, manifest, intentfilter

I need to create an intent-filter for CPP files. Today I found out that some users are using lower-case file extensions (*.cpp) and other users use the upper-case variant (*.CPP). What I didn't check is for mixed-case (e.g. *.Cpp).

The current design of android:pathPattern is pure "ahem". Is there any way to make that check case independent without extending these four pathPattern lines to 15 lines?

Many thanks in advance.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cpp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.cpp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.cpp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.cpp" />
</intent-filter>
```